# Error using socket_bind() on a shared hosting provider

Tags: php, sockets

I have a server service script and client service script written in PHP using PHP's sockets API. They are working fine in localhost, but after uploading those two scripts to my hosting account on [ipage](https://www.ipage.com/ipage/index.html), the server script is giving me an error on the `socket_bind` call. Here is the code I am using on the server:

```
$host = "my_own_hosting"; 
$port = 25003; 
$message = "Hello Client"; 
set_time_limit(0); 
// create socket 
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) 
    or die("Could not create socket\n"); 
// bind socket to port (this is the call that returns the error)
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) 
    or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// put server into passive state and listen for connections 
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) 
    or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
```

Any ideas on why this call is not working?

Comment: which error? I left my crystal ball at work (I can try and guess your cheap hosting provider blocks PHP socket API calls for safety reasons or you are calling PHP cgi web server which does not have root privileges: http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php#68709)

Comment: Cannot bind to socket 
What error is it ?

Comment: is the port in use by another service (try netstat to check)? are you binding to an actual ip assigned to an interface o the machine in which you are running you script (try ifconfig or ipconfig /all if you are on windowsto check)?

Comment: $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n")

Comment: Can you give me a sample code for server and client which I can upload in my hosting? @elcodedocle

Comment: trust the manual before its comments: use http://php.net/manual/en/function.getprotobyname.php or SOL_TCP for determining the third parameter instead of 0. You have only provided the code for creating the socket. What about the binding call that's returning the error? Where is your `socket_listen` call on the server? Where is your `socket_connect` call on the client? Where is your code!!!

Comment: $host = "my_own_hosting";
$port = 25003;
$message = "Hello Client";
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// put server into passive state and listen for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
I am having 'Could not bind to socket Error' @elcodedocle

Comment: $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

Here is socket connect client code. @elcodedocle

Comment: good. And you are having trouble with `$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");` right?

Comment: Yes I am having trouble with this .... @elcodedocle
what do I do now?

Comment: And `"my_own_hosting"` is what? It must be the ip address of the interface you want the service to be accepting connections from.

Comment: What do you mean when you say your own hosting? You mean a machine you own or a hosting service account you have set up on a hosting service provider?

Comment: this is my hostname, where I have uploaded these files
I have a domain on iPage. @elcodedocle

Comment: use the interface ip you want to bind your socket to instead of a hostname

Comment: How will I get the ip ? 
I tried that too , I found out my domain's ip address from this site https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html
I used it but didnot work @elcodedocle

Comment: iPage is probably not going to allow you to bind to sockets since its most likely a shared server environment. You are going to need dedicated or VPS hosting environment for that.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost:

**Use [`socket_strerror`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-strerror.php) and [`socket_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-last-error.php) to figure out your problem:**

```
if (!($result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port)){ 
    die(socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
}
```

You are trying to run your server script on a shared PHP hosting provider ([ipage](https://www.ipage.com/ipage/index.html)).

These kind of providers do not generally allow to use the PHP sockets interface to build your own services, or implement harsh restrictions (Such as allowed ports or protocols for running the service) to avoid abuse and prevent safety issues. Either you comply with them or change your hosting service to one that fits your needs.

It seems your provider allows using the sockets interface though.

(You can check it out by searching for socket on http://www.hostingreviewbox.com/features/ipage-php/ although it's best if you make sure of it by running [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) on your account yourself, or even better: Open up a support ticket with your hosting provider and ask them if sockets are in any way restricted on your account.)

Then you should make sure of 2 things:

1. ***Are you using the proper ip address on `$host`?***

You can `ping my_own_hosting` and see what you get or even better, add this code snippet to your server script for figuring out your server's public ip at runtime:

```
  $host = my_ip();
  echo "my ip address is $host\n";

  function my_ip($dest='8.8.8.8', $port=53)
  {
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
    socket_connect($socket, $dest, $port);
    socket_getsockname($socket, $addr, $port);
    socket_close($socket);
    return $addr;
  }
```

(from http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php#49368)

2. ***Is the port you are trying to use already in use or restricted?***

Try to use a different port or ask your hosting provider about it.

On a side note:

**Trust the PHP manual before its comments**: You should use [getprotobyname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getprotobyname.php) or [SOL_TCP](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.constants.php) for determining the third parameter of [socket_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php) instead of just sending 0.

Lastly, you should **consider using [socket_create_listen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create-listen.php)** instead of `socket_create` + `socket_bind` + `socket_listen`. Or, for this particular case, [stream_socket_server](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php) and [stream_socket_accept](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-accept.php). Like the PHP manual shows, they are way more practical:

```
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://{$host}:{$port}", $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket) {
  echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
  while ($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
    fwrite($conn, 'The local time is ' . date('n/j/Y g:i a') . "\n");
    fclose($conn);
  }
  fclose($socket);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me some VPS hosting link where I can do some free trial,
Thanks a lot for your feedback

Comment: There are plenty of them. I use AWS EC2. You should check out webhostingtalk.com or some place like that to see reviews and get info on what might fit your needs.